# How to abort or close bulk API jobs from api?

Tags: bulk-api

Salesforce support requested to abort bulk data jobs from API, we tried doing it via UI, but salesforce support said it did not work! looking for ways to do it via rest, soap or any other ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abort bulk data jobs using CURL command as below

```
curl -H 'X-SFDC-Session: <<insert session id here>>' -H 'Content-Type:text/csv;charset=UTF-8' -d @job.xml <<insert your org endpoint url here>>services/async/38.0/job/<<insert job id you want to abort>>
```

create file job.xml with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <state>Aborted</state>
</jobInfo>
```

If you want to close job change above file to `<state>Closed</state>`

Salesforce documentation - [Bulk API Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_asynch.pdf) please see section "Walk Through a Bulk Query Sample".

Comment: Also When u try to click on close job hyperlink it reloads the entire page. Instead of that you could simply click open in new tab. It will save your time and could close multiple jobs.
In the end close all your newly open windows.